# Posting to facebook company page with cron php server side

Tags: cron, facebook-php-sdk

I am looking to update a facebook company page directly using cron and php.

Can anyone shed some light on the simplest current correct method of generating a page access token then extending that so that I may use that in my php script that I will run by cron?

I just want to write two simple php scripts, one that generates this extended page token by me opening that page within a browser monthly, and the other which would be executed by cron using that page token for automatic authentication independent of a users browser (I want my server to authenticate by itself) to post a simple text message to a company page that I am an admin of.

I am just looking to send short messages at particular times to the company page direct from the server without a person having to be involved.

Thanks

Comment: Hardly think this question should be closed and down voted when Anvesh had already replied with the correct response to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as you need to post to your company's Page, then you would require **Page Access Token** and coincidentally it never expires onece generated.

1. First you will have to implement `login` feature of Facebook along with [extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/) `manage_pages` permission. The easiest and fastest way to do the same would be to create an App and then using Graph Explorer with the app selected, generate access token with the `manage_pages` permission. If you want to implement the same you might want to look at this [example](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php). 
   **Edit:** When using Graph Explorer you would be required to navigate to `/me/accounts` end point, there you would find the required access token for the page in question along with other pages you might administer.
2. After you have obtained the Page Access Token, you may then use the same to perform the posting of update using the [PHP SDK's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) [`api` method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) after you have set the access token of your Page in the SDK with [`setAccessToken()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-setAccessToken/). Or you may just perform a HTTP POST with your `message` to your page at the endpoint

   `https://graph.facebook.com/pageID/feed?access_token=Your_page_access_token`

Comment: Thanks Anvesh for a great answer, this is just what I was looking for, am I right to assume that the user access token generated in graph explorer with manage_pages permission is then considered the Page access token? I ask this because when I then log into Access Token Tool it lists this generated token as a user token. Do I just use this generated token in my php script and using cron it will then allow posts to that page as is logged in as 'me' on facebook?

Comment: Also when looking at that token in Access Token Tool Debugger, it says that token expires in 'about an hour'?? Am I generating the wrong kind of token?

Comment: @RayAndison, I am sorry I forgot to mention about the `/me/accounts` end point from where you would retrieve your access token. The access token generated and displayed in Graph explorer is just User Access Token and not Page Access Token. When you retrieve it, you may use the same to post on your behalf on your page.