# Post on facebook page by cron

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have read all the postings related to the title. But I have a very simple question. It will be very helpful if anyone can answer that.

What is me/account page in facebook?

I got many postings here such as

[Posting to facebook company page with cron php server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503122/posting-to-facebook-company-page-with-cron-php-server-side)

Everything is explained, but I know this sounds funny, but I stuck in the easiest step.

"When using Graph Explorer you would be required to navigate to /me/accounts end point,"

Please help me.

Please check the code

```
include 'includes/facebook.php';
$app_id = "XXXXXXXXXX";
$app_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$page_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
$my_url = "http://XXXXXXXXXXX.com";
$page_access_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

//Create the facebook object
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $app_id,
 'secret' => $app_secret,
 'cookie' => true
));

//Write to the Page wall
try {
    $attachment = array(
                'access_token' => $page_access_token,
                'message'=> "Hello World"
        );

   $result = $facebook->api('/639386542780904/feed', 'post',  $attachment);

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "error";
  //  ...
   // mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

me/accounts is used to get a facebook page acces token, so that your app will post as that page. Elsewhere, your app will post as you on that page.